# How to assign a keyword to Group of Test Cases at one time in TestLink?

Tags: testing, keyword, testlink

I want to add a keyword to some of the test cases in my test specification. May I know whether there is any easy way of doing it other than adding the keyword to each test case manually?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign keyword to multiple test cases under specification's node.

1. Select Desktop item from top nav bar menu in Testlink
2. From the left select Test Specification -> Assign Keywords
3. Specifications' tree is opened - select the needed node (test suite)
4. In Keyword Assignment frame from the right assign with > button keyword from available ones to Keywords to be assigned.. and click Save
   As result all test cases under the selected node will get the assigned keyword.

You may also filter test cases by some of available filter fields and then assign the keyword (using the process described above) but with "Assign ONLY to filtered Test Cases" checkbox activated, so only filtered TCs will get the needed keyword.